# Batch download on an ssh session

Tags: python, ssh

I need to download some satellite images from sentinel2 via python script. I have already tested locally on a small amount of files and the script works correctly. Now I should run this script on an ssh session. My question is, how do I leave the script running (downloading) even if I close the ssh connection? Is it sufficient to launch the script in  background (`python3 main.py &`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tools for jobs like this: for example check this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session).

You can start with [`screen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).

```
$ screen  # initiates a screen session
```

In the screen session, do:

```
$ python my_scripts.py
```

When the script is running, you can detach from the screen session with `Ctrl-A`+`D`.

The script will run in "background" and you can leave your current ssh session.

For batch downloads, you can shoot-up multiple screen sessions. You could assign a name for each screen when you initiate the session. In this way you can run multiple scripts, one in each session.

To check opened sessions:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    96185.pts-5.xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx   (2022年07月01日 17时39分06秒) (Detached)
    95231.pts-5.xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx   (2022年07月01日 17时20分40秒) (Detached)
```

And to reattach to a specific session:

```
$ screen -r 96185
```

But before you do all of that, you might want to check there're enough resource (disk space, bandwidth, etc.).